# Как в Python pandas, перенести столбик из одной таблицы Excel другую, без создания новой таблицы?

Tags: python, pandas, excel, xlsx

сразу извиняюсь, если такой вопрос уже был разобран, но ответа на него я аока что нигде не нашёл.
Задача: переместить весь столбик номер 8 "Grade"/его значения из таблицы one.xlsx в таблицу two.xlsx.
В таблице two.xlsx тоже есть столбики с данными, поэтому переписывать таблицу по новой не нужно. Только сам столбец.
Пробовал с pandas, но панда переписывает мне всю таблицу по новой и стирает всё кроме самого столбика.
Мучаюсь уже вторую неделю с этим(
Буду очень благодарен!

**Мой код:**

```
import pandas as pd

cols = [12]

sopimus_tunnukset = pd.read_excel('./one.xlsx', index_col='Grade', usecols=cols)
sopimus_tunnukset.head()

df = pd.DataFrame(sopimus_tunnukset)

df.to_excel('./two.xlsx', startcol=3)

print(sopimus_tunnukset)
```

**Вот скрины с таблиц:**

[image: one.xlsx]

[image: two.xlsx]

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно указать режим(mode). a = добавление/w = перезапись.

```
df2 = df1.copy()
with pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx') as writer:
    df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet_name_1')
    df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet_name_2')

with pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx',
                     mode='a') as writer:  
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet_name_3')
```

Comment: Спасибо, я попробую этот способ и отпишусь вам,